# Compiling individual webpage tables into a single Excel readable table

Tags: web-scraping

I would like to create a master list of contact information for all Chiropractors in Arizona.  The board website lists all the Chiropractors  [here](http://www.azchiroboard.us/DaEngine.asp) however, I have to click through to see each individual address and phone number.

How can I get all of the information about each Chiropractor in to a single spreadsheet row format?

Comment: Do you have access to the code / to the database or only to the webpage you linked ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You'll need to make your question more specific to get useful answers: You need to "scrape" the website with the help of `php`, `python` or some other scripting language. If you know how to use such tools, please clarify. Generating a CSV or Excel file is the easy part-- your question has (almost) nothing to do with excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy. In your first sheet do `Data > External data > From website`. Paste the URL, select the main table and do `Next` and put it in A1.

In VBA Editor paste the following formula and execute it. It will retrieve all data from the website and paste it in `Sheet2`. The rest is just reorganizing the data which is not the topic of your question so I leave it up to you.

```
Sub ExtractAllData()
    Dim dest As Range, license As Range
    Dim license_no As String

    Worksheets("Feuil2").Select
    Set dest = Worksheets("Feuil2").Range("A1")
    Set license = Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("C3")
    Do Until license.Value = ""
        license_no = Mid(license.Value, 1, InStr(1, license.Value, " "))
        With Worksheets("Feuil2").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "URL;http://www.azchiroboard.us/ProDetail.asp?LicenseNo=" & license_no, Destination:= _
            dest)
            .Name = "ProDetail.asp?LicenseNo=" & license_no
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebTables = "1"
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
        Set dest = Range("A65535").End(xlUp)
        Set dest = dest.Offset(1, 0)
        Set license = license.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

For the record, it took me 1 minute to figure out how to retrieve the data from the main table. 1 minute to figure out that the link just calls a PHP page with the license number. 1 minute to record the macro and then 5 minutes to adapt it and fix errors I had made.

Comment: Thank you!  I was interested in having the data for each Chiropractor occupy a single row, but in this case I wrote a second macro for that.  It took me a lot longer than 8 minutes, but I guess it's true what they say about things are easy when you know how. . .